# Is there a way to prevent start of a durable azure function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Durable function (.NET 6) triggered with httpTrigger, I'm trying to prevent start of the function based on the parameters received in the http request.

The code I tried so far :

```
 [FunctionName(nameof(StartOrchestrator))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> StartOrchestrator(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
    {
        var stringContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var parameter = GetParam(stringContent);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.MyParam))
        {
            //Here I want to prevent start of the orchestration with a 400 bad request error
            return req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Request doesn't contains MyParam");
        }
        var instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(RunOrchestrator), parameter);
        return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
    }
```

The result I'm getting :

[image]

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to ?

Comment: What happens in `GetParam`? Is `stringContent` null, possibly? Add a breakpoint in the Function and investigate what's happening. Why are you getting this strange message? Http status 500 indicates an internal server error, while the description says Bad Request (which is Http status 400). In short: we need more info.

Comment: There is not particular issue in the GetParam, I'm entering inside the if, the issue is why im getting 500 instead of 400.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint on the first line of code, to make sure you're entering the Function. See what happens when you step through.

Comment: Thanks to put me on the right direction, I finally found out I had " Synchronous operations are disallowed." Exception

Answer (score 0):

It should be a semaphore issue, two threads are created right here and azure functions doesn't support synchronouse operations so this is where the 500 is coming from.
The solution  is to set the variable FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE
[image]

Comment: This should not be used. As the warning is saying it's only a short term workaround. The good way is to not use synchronous operations in durable orchestration.